# Requirejs Typeahead Is Not a Function Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, typeahead

So I've been having this issue with Typeahead where whenever I call it the console is returning an error of: TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function.

I wasn't having this issue with a previous version of Typeahead. 0.9.3 precisely. This issue started happening when I updated to 0.11.1. I'm using RequireJS to load all my modules and scripts.

Comment: Do your dev tools show the typeahead library being loaded?

Comment: @Starscream1984 Yup. Typeahead was working fine until I did the update. Now I just keep getting typeahead is not a function.

Comment: the docs don't suggest any change in the syntax - if you breakpoint the line which the error first occurs on - has the library loaded at that point?

Comment: @Starscream1984 Yes.

Comment: @Starscream1984 I have been at this for hours. Tried both typeahead.bundle and typeahead.jquery. I can see the function in the source of Typeahead but its just not recognizing it. One thing I noticed though is that whenever I try to find Typeahead's implementation in my code (using PHPStorm) my IDE fails to find the source. This isnt happening with any of the other libraries/plugins that I'm using.

Comment: Weird. I don't know PHPStorm, but if your IDE can't see the typeahead source file, then it follows that the served webpage wouldn't either. Your error message says to me it could be one of two things: 1) the script is not loaded - `typeahead` is never initialised as a function for jquery objects. or 2) some other script later sets `typeahead` on jquery objects as null, undefined, or a non-object type. I think it's likely 1)

Comment: @Starscream1984 That's what I initially believed to be the case as well. Which is why I put a copy of the old version of Typeahead in my JS working directory and amended my Requirejs config file to point to it. That made it work. I then amended back the config file to point to the new version and the error crept up again. I triple checked the source of the file, everything is there. Im using bower to fetch my packages. Deleted my bower dependencies, installed again, copied the file again. Nothing.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md There was a rewrite change from `0.9` to `0.11` in `0.10`

Comment: Yup, thanks for pointing that out. Completely breaking change from 0.9 to 0.10.